# How to insert element into existing HTML by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="main-photo" style="height: 304.875px;">
     <img class="big-thumb" src="blob:http://localhost:8080/cf4ffcff-7322-44dc-8c46-3c29ef165378" style="top: -27px;">
</div>
```

I need result when mouse hover :

```
<div class="main-photo" style="height: 304.875px;">
    <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="blob:http://localhost:8080/cf4ffcff-7322-44dc-8c46-3c29ef165378">
         <img class="big-thumb" src="blob:http://localhost:8080/cf4ffcff-7322-44dc-8c46-3c29ef165378" style="top: -27px;">
    </a>
</div>
```

I try something like this, use jQuery, when hover mouse over image (stub idea):

```
$('.main-photo').hover(function() {
    $('.main-photo ').append()..attr('class', 'fancybox fancybox.iframe');
});
```

but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap/unwrap the anchor element, also it will be better to derive the source of the anchor dynamically from the image

```js
$('.main-photo').hover(function() {
  var $img = $(this).find('img'),
    $a = $('<a />', {
      'class': 'fancybox fancybox.iframe',
      href: $img.attr('src')
    });
  $img.wrap($a)
}, function() {
  $(this).find('img').unwrap()
});
```

```css
.main-photo {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.fancybox {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-photo" style="height: 304.875px;">
  <img class="big-thumb" src="//placehold.it/64X64" style="top: -27px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
$('.main-photo').hover(function() { 
   $(this).find("img").wrap('<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="blob:http://localhost:8080/cf4ffcff-7322-44dc-8c46-3c29ef165378"></a>');
}, function(){
   $(this).find('img').unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main-photo').hover(function() {
    $('.main-photo ').append()..attr('class', 'fancybox fancybox.iframe');
});
```

Try to change your code into this

```
$('.main-photo').hover(function() {
    $('.main-photo ').append("<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="blob:http://localhost:8080/cf4ffcff-7322-44dc-8c46-3c29ef165378">");
    $(".big-thumb").append("</a>");
});
```